# Default product short description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

On my woocommerce site I want to add the text "Only available in stores" to all my product's short description, and also have that same text be default for all future products I add.

I had a search but the solutions seemed way to complex for me. Is there some code I can paste in the functions.php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem easily. You need to some code push to theme functions.php or use [code snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin. This code only works when the WooCommerce product short description is empty.

```
function wp_woocommerce_short_description_if_empty(){
    global $post;
    if (empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
        $post_excerpt = '<p class="default-short-desc">';
        $post_excerpt .= 'Your Custom Message Here.';
        $post_excerpt .= '</p>';
        echo $post_excerpt;
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wp_woocommerce_short_description_if_empty', 21);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! How can I make the text font size smaller?

Comment: I made the text smaller by adding '<p class="default-short-desc"; style = "font-size:10px" >';

Comment: You can use inline style or use CSS class.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this for your default product description, you can Add Custom Text before/after the Product Short Description

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'woo_add_text_after_excerpt_single_product', 20, 1 );
function woo_add_text_after_excerpt_single_product( $post_excerpt ){

    /* Method 1: Add Custom Text before the Product Short Description on product page */
    /* $content= '<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
      <li>'.__('Only available in stores').'</li>
      </ul>';
      return $content.'<br>'.$post_excerpt; 
    */
    
    /* Method 2: Add Custom Text after the Product Short Description on product page */
    $post_excerpt .= '<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
    <li>'.__('Only available in stores').'</li>
    </ul>';
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

**Note:  Add Custom Text before the Product Short Description on the product page - code is commented** so you can uncomment accordingly.